# Element with no height, margin, padding, or border still occupies space because of margins of elements below it

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a list of elements like this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner first">First</div>
  <div class="inner">Second</div>
</div>
```

If I apply the following style

```
.inner {
   height: 30px;
   margin: 10px;
}

.first {
   height: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

and assuming that padding and borders are already 0, the element's presence still occupies some space (presumably because of the margin of the element blow it) which it wouldn't if element's display property were set to `none`.

This is causing problems when I use CSS animations to make the first element disappear and for the second to smoothly come up. See the snippet below

```js
$(".first").addClass("hide").bind("webkitAnimationEnd animationEnd", function () {
  $(".first").addClass("hidden")
  });
```

```css
.inner {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hide {
  animation-name: disappear;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.hidden {display: none}

@keyframes disappear {
  from {
    height: default;
    margin: default;
  }
  to {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner first">First</div><div class="inner">Second</div>
</div>
```

In this situation, how can I manage to make the first element disappear and then I could completely remove it from the page?

Note that I've already gone through similar questions on SO and this is not a case of whitespace between two elements causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add css like :

`body{margin: 0;}`

Comment: It solves my problem but I still don't understand why it works. i.e. why body's margin was causing this behavior?

Comment: Didn't work for me... did nothing